# How to test custom SearchDelegate?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to test my custom `SearchDelegate`. Example test would be checking after how many characters it starts giving suggestions.

I wrote two example tests which somehow affect each other. They're both the same, but the test that appears later in the code always fail when I run them together.

While debugging I found out `FutureBuilder` in `buildSuggestions` method doesn't wait for `searchEngine.search(query)` future to finish but it happens only for the second test.

I've already tried adding a `test.runAsync` with `Future.delayed` inside after tapping search icon. Also, I simplified the case to make it more readable.

You can find the full code here: https://github.com/pmiara/search-delegate-test-fail
or look at it below.

Application code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Entity {
  final String value;

  Entity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : value = json['value'];
}

class MySearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  final MySearchEngine searchEngine;

  MySearchDelegate({@required this.searchEngine});

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Entity>>(
      future: searchEngine.search(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Entity>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.hasData) {
          final entities = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: entities.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text(entities[index].value),
              onTap: () => close(context, entities[index]),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Column();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Entity>>(
      future: searchEngine.search(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Entity>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.hasData) {
          final entities = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: entities.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text(entities[index].value),
              onTap: () {
                query = entities[index].value;
                showResults(context);
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Column();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MySearchEngine {
  Future<List<Entity>> search(String query) async {
    final jsonEntities =
        await rootBundle.loadString('test_resources/entities.json');
    final entities = jsonDecode(jsonEntities)
        .map<Entity>((json) => Entity.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
    return entities;
  }
}

class TestHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MySearchDelegate delegate;

  const TestHomePage({@required this.delegate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () async {
                  showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    delegate: delegate,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Run to see what tests should "see"
void main() => runApp(
      TestHomePage(
        delegate: MySearchDelegate(
          searchEngine: MySearchEngine(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Test file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:search_delegate_test/search_delegate_problem.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('First test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final delegate = MySearchDelegate(
      searchEngine: MySearchEngine(),
    );
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      TestHomePage(
        delegate: delegate,
      ),
    );
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.search));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), 'query');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(ListTile), findsNWidgets(3));
  });

  testWidgets('Second test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final delegate = MySearchDelegate(
      searchEngine: MySearchEngine(),
    );
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      TestHomePage(
        delegate: delegate,
      ),
    );
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.search));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), 'query');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.byType(ListTile), findsNWidgets(3));
  });
}
```

pubsec.yaml:

```
name: search_delegate_test
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any

flutter:
  assets:
    - test_resources/

  uses-material-design: true
```

test_resources/entities.json:

```
[
  {
    "value": "abc"
  },
  {
    "value": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "value": "123def"
  }
]
```

And the result of `flutter doctor` (I'm using Android Studio):

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Linux, locale pl_PL.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Error that I get:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly 3 matching nodes in the widget tree
  Actual: ?:<zero widgets with type "ListTile" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but some were expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///path/to/project/search_delegate_test/test/serach_delegate_problem_test.dart:37:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:118:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:630:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:613:14)
#10     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1010:24)
#16     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1007:15)
#17     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:116:22)
#18     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)
#25     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)
#30     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#45     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
#46     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
  file:///path/to/project/search_delegate_test/test/serach_delegate_problem_test.dart line 37
The test description was:
  Second test
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: Second test
```